# Rate-limiting my program from sending too many SES emails via SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to send 10000s of individual mails at once; possibly from a large `for` loop:

```
for user in _10000_users:
    msg  = generate_message( user)
    if(ses.can_send_more_messages == False):
        sleep( 0.1) #to throttle ourselves
    ses.send_message( msg)
```

But I am worried about the **70 mails/second throttle** on our SES account. So I want my program to respect this limit by **inspecting the queue** and wait if it has exceeded the limit and sending again only if its clear.

I am using boto in Python to interface with SQS. And I expect only a single machine to send messages, although in future multiple machines may send messages in parallel being ignorant of each other.

How can I do rate-limiting of emails to 70 per second by inspecting the queue or using a Python-specific technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute messages per second rate like the next code sample shows:

```
from time import time

time_started = time()
messages_sent = 0.
MAX_PER_SEC = 70

for user in _10000_users:
    msg = generate_message(user)
    if messages_sent / (time() - time_started) >= MAX_PER_SEC:  # Rate condition
        sleep(0.1)
    ses.send_message(msg)
    messages_sent += 1
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the above works, trying to use the logic within a multithreaded application. Thanks.